# How to use SSIS variable outside Main() method in SSIS Script Task

Tags: c#, variables, ssis, etl, script-task

I am using SSIS script task to send automated e-mail based on a few pre-conditions. As part of that I have a SendAutomatedEmail() method and in this method I am passing two variables mailServer and recipient. In doing so I run into the error "object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

Tried to use a constructor but that did not resolve the problem.

```
class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        string mailServer = Dts.Variables["User::varServer"].Value.ToString();  
        string recipient = Dts.Variables["User::varRecipient"].Value.ToString(); 

        server msr = new server(mserv, rec);
    }

    public class server
    {
        string ms;
    string r;

        public result(string mserv, string rec)
        {
           ms = mserv;
           r = rec;
        }
    }
}

using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
    try
    {
        //do something
    }
    catch
    {
        //catch exception
    }
    }

public static void SendAutomatedEmail(string htmlString, string recipient = "user@domain.com")
{

 try
 {
     string mailServer = Dts.Variables["User::varServer"].Value.ToString();  //error "object reference not set to an instance of an object."
     string recipient = Dts.Variables["User::varRecipient"].Value.ToString();   //error "object reference not set to an instance of an object."

     MailMessage message = new MailMessage("it@domain.com", recipient);
     message .IsBodyHtml = true;
     message .Body = htmlString;
     message .Subject = "Test Email";

     SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
     var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");
     client.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;
     client.Send(message);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     //catch exception
 }

}

}
```

I should be able to pass the value to the variable seamlessly in the SendAutomatedEmail() method.

Comment: Just remove the `static` option from the function

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to declare 2 variables in Program Class, read the values within the Main() function and assign these values to the local variables. Then you can use local variables outside of Main() function.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{

    string mailServer;
     string recipient;

    public void Main()
    {
    try
    {
        mailServer = Dts.Variables["User::varServer"].Value.ToString();
        recipient = Dts.Variables["User::varRecipient"].Value.ToString();

    }
    catch
    {
        //catch exception
    }
    }

 private class sendEMail
 {
    public static void SendAutomatedEmail(string htmlString, string recipient = "user@domain.com")
    {

     try
     {

         MailMessage message = new MailMessage("it@domain.com", recipient);
         message .IsBodyHtml = true;
         message .Body = htmlString;
         message .Subject = "Test Email";

         SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailServer);
         var AuthenticationDetails = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");
         client.Credentials = AuthenticationDetails;
         client.Send(message);
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         //catch exception
     }

    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Hadi, I did try this previously and was getting this Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.

Comment: Remove the `static` option from the function

Comment: @user25407 use `public void SendAutomatedEmail()`

Comment: Hi @Hadi, The function SendAutomatedEmail() is in a different private class.

Comment: @user25407 then keep the code as it is and try to remove the `static` option